# sql - calendar table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, calendar

I want to create a program where a person will be able to save his schedule.
For example a doctor will be able to save an appointment.

I want to save every appointment in a mysql database. So I need to create a calendar/appointments table. In every appointment I want to save these information:

- day
- month
- year
- start (hour)
- finish (hour)
- participant (the patient)

I was thinking of creating a big table with all the possible appointments for some years (ex. 20 years) and leaving the participant column empty, meaning there is no appointment. If an appointment is made the the participant field will be filled.

Is there a better way of doing it? Can someone provide some guidelines and if possible an example? I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
table appointments
--------------------
id               int (primary key, auto_increment)
participant_id   int (foreign key to persons table)
starts           datetime
ends             datetime
```

Then only save the real appointments and not empty ones. Storing fakes is never a good idea.

Comment: I understand. The just thought it would be better creating every combo. Thanks.

Comment: Storing actual appointment slots isn't the same thing as storing fakes.